# Are there Edge cases with swapping 2 values in memory using dereferenced pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote this simple function in C to swap the Value in 2 addresses in memory:

```
void pointersswap (int *ptr1, int *ptr2) 
{
    *ptr1 = *ptr1*(*ptr2);
    *ptr2 = *ptr1/(*ptr2);
    *ptr1 = *ptr1/(*ptr2);
}
```

I've been told there is an "edge case" that this program can encounter.
You can assume the input is correct (ptr1 and ptr2 actually hold address values and these addresses point to the memory where there's 2 ints which aren't 0). Math always checks out, even if either dereferenced pointer holds a negative number, or both are negative, or fractions.

For reference, this code Shouldn't have the same issue / edge case:

```
void pointersswap (int *ptr1, int *ptr2) 
{
    int temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}
```

What am I missing? are there really any limitations / edge cases in the first function?

Small clarification: assume there's not overflow / loss of information.

Comment: What if the result of multiplication of `*ptr1` and `*ptr2` is greater than the max value that can be stored in int? Also what if any of them points to 0?

Comment: Using XOR instead of multiplication and division is better because it won't cause overflow to loss some data.

Comment: Assume input is correct and there is now overflow or loss of information due to division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been mislead, and so I mislead anyone who tried answering my question and for that I apologize. The two codes had the same edge case, which was that both pointers point to the same address, like MikeCAT suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, "expressions" like `*ptr1/*ptr2` won't work because `/*` is interpreted as the beginning of comments in C.

After replacing `/*` with `/ *`, there are (at least) two cases in which the function won't work:

- When the multiplication overflows.
- When pointers to the same variable is passed to both `a` and `b`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void pointersswap (int *ptr1, int *ptr2) 
{
    *ptr1 = *ptr1*(*ptr2);
    *ptr2 = *ptr1/ *ptr2;
    *ptr1 = *ptr1/ *ptr2;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    a = 999999; b = 888888;
    printf("before: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    pointersswap(&a, &b);
    printf("after ; a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);

    a = 12345;
    printf("before: a = %d\n", a);
    pointersswap(&a, &a);
    printf("after : a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5B5MVn7I9NRG0Lrn):

```
before: a = 999999, b = 888888
after ; a = 891245, b = -192
before: a = 12345
after : a = 1
```

Comment: A third non-working case is when division by zero occurs.

Comment: @IanAbbott Zero is excluded by the question.

Comment: Regarding the second bullet, perhaps as a solution one could at least mark the parameter pointers as `restrict` to make it clear that there shouldn't be overlap. I believe a XOR swap also suffers from this issue if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: code fixed, using /(*ptr2) to avoid /* comment - this code was not written in an IDE. Overflow was not the issue I was notified about. Input should be correct meaning not both pointers point to the same thing.